# How do you flush HTML in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, flush

In PHP, it's possible to flush HTML which is done mostly after the headers of an HTML file like in this example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flush Example Page</title>
  <link rel="styles.css" href="my.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
<?php flush(); ?>
<body>...
```

How do you do this with Spring MVC? If this practice isn't optimal for some reason, by all means, elaborate.

Comment: I think you html has to be inside a php block to be printed. Another question is why you want to flush explicitly, why not just let the webserver do it when the buffer is full ?

Comment: I was watching this O'Reilly Velocity talk to make websites load below 1s. Flushing is the technique they use so I started wondering how to do this in my Spring projects.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YV1nKLWoARQ

Comment: I think you should have put that information into the original question. If you knew a bit about Spring MVC you should have asked about "how to flush  headers in view to optimise browser load time". I interpreted the question and the php reference as a complete noob question, hence the answer.

Comment: Flushing initial bytes of HTML is an important thing currently ( http 1 and http2 days )
Not only flushing head tag, but html content required to do meaningful paint.

Answer (score 0):

I would never use flush explicitly in a Spring MVC view, let me explain why.

The idea behind flushing is that the browser will get the links to javascript/css resources faster, and since it can parse them in parallel, there is a theoretical chance that the site will load faster.

Older Spring MVC application will typically load data into the model inside the controller. So there is no IO in the view except writing to the output stream, and then flushing after the header have no actual effect.
If you have a modern single page application, there is typically none or very little IO when loading the first page that contains the JavaScript/Css links, the actual data is loaded through REST services as JSON, so again no need to flush.

The reason flushing is used in PHP, is because it often mixes the rendering and the database IO, and then it may make sense to flush.

On Tomcat the output buffer size is 8K by default, if you can fill this with headers, and some of the body without any (significant) IO, there is no need to flush.

If you look at the timeline in the browser's developer tools, and there is a long idle period from making the initial page request, until resources start loading, you may have something that can be optimised by flushing. However it is probably the last optimisations I would do (after resource bundling, http cacheing, etc.) In Angular(2) you can even pre-render the initial page, because the initialization of large applications takes time (and the flushing is again a mute point).

Answer (score 0):

### Looking at how things work

With an HTTP response you have the status line, headers and a body (let's ignore trailers, since browsers mostly don't let you do anything useful with these).
In the happy path for MVC, you collect all your data, set any headers you want on the response and then the template that you're using as your view will be used as the response body.
In the error path, an exception is thrown which overrides the default status code and changes which view will be used (usually some other template).

So in the error path, a flush in the main template is irrelevant since it wouldn't be used, and in the happy path, the majority of the time is spent collecting data and so the brief time spent writing out the template is largely irrelevant.

### Basic Strategies

If you want to send the HTML head before the data is collected, you have a couple of options,
but the problem with these approaches is that they interfere with (i.e. break) Spring's normal error handling:

1. Write some HTML to the response in the controller, then collect the data and finally render the rest in the view template. E.g.:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"); // Needed as Spring won't have set this yet.
response.getWriter().write(htmlStartIncludingHead);
response.getWriter().flush();
Model model = collectDataAndbuildModel();
return "myViewWithoutHead";
```

2. Move the task of collecting data (directly or indirectly, synchronously or asynchronously) to be done inside the template in order to make flushes there be useful.
   If you flush before you wait to retrieve some amount of data, then the user can receive already completed content while waiting.
   In JSP you can flush using `<% out.flush(); %>` or `<% response.getWriter().flush(); %>`.
   In FreeMarker, it has a dedicated flush directive: `<#flush>`.

### Towards a working solution

In order to experiment with a solution which tries various approaches to address error handling whilst moving the data collection to occur while running the template,
I've made a proof of concept where the Model's values in the Controller are changed to Callables and/or Futures:
https://github.com/scrhartley/freemarker-streaming-poc
I've also made a version for JSP which focuses solely on using different types of Futures as Model values:
https://github.com/scrhartley/jsp-streaming-poc

The tricks used for error handling boil down to:

1. Output a meta refresh tag to perform a client side redirect when an error occurs
2. Output a script tag to perform some JavaScript page manipulation when an error occurs
3. Use a template level equivalent to try/catch, allowing you to output some fallback content when an error occurs.

   - FreeMarker has [attempt/recover](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_attempt.html) directives. Attempt swallows flushes inside it and so needs to be used accordingly.
   - JSP has the JSTL catch tag.

### Warning / Troubleshooting

HTTP streaming may not work if your servers are configured incorrectly. For notes on buffering and Nagle's algorithm see:
https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/improving-performance-with-http-streaming-ba9e72c66408

Answer (score -1):

I don't even know where to begin... ;)

Your PHP example mixes the model, the view and controller, in Spring MVC they are separate things.

The actual rendering takes place in the view, typically JSP, or Thymeleaf templates. The model contains the data for the view and is configured by the Controller which also decides which view should be shown to the user.

If you have only done PHP, and you're completely new to Spring, you are looking at quite the learning curve. Maybe you should start with a tutorial, like [Spring boot web tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) and then read a little about the MVC pattern. And then ask some more specific questions later

Comment: It would have made more sense to pose the question in context of views indeed, like JSP and Thymeleaf. I guess for JSP I would use o.flush(); o.close(); For Thymeleaf I wasn't able to find info about flushing though.

Comment: you should never call flush() explicitly, leave that to the servlet container. Also I would not recommend Velocity, use Thymeleaf instead, much better IMHO.

Comment: O'Reilly Velocity is an information technologies conference :). I haven't used Velocity, the intention is to use Thymeleaf.

Comment: I will add another answer relating to flush, since the comments can't be long enough.

Comment: Flushing initial bytes to network stream is very important phenomenon works under low level core parts of web. Spring MVC is high level abstraction.  which should be doing flush by it's own opinionated way. or should allow the developer to do. it is not about PHP or Spring MVC. Flushing should still happen and and should be possible.